# cmds.confirmDialog, Help "Question Mark" button configuration support for Maya

Tags: python, windows, scripting, operating-system, maya

In the documentation - https://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2020/CHS/Maya-Tech-Docs/CommandsPython/confirmDialog.html

They never address how to configure a message for the HELP "question mark" button.
Here is a snippet of my code:

```
cmds.confirmDialog(
        title="Wdinow", 
        message="Do somthing",
        messageAlign="center",
        button=['Import','Cancel'],
        defaultButton="Import",
        cancelButton="Cancel",
        backgroundColor=[0, 0, 0] #black
    )
```

This is what the window looks like:

[image]

I need to configure a message to pop up when they click the help "question mark" button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can find out, the `cmds.confirmDialog` wrapper does not provide a hook for [WhatsThis](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwhatsthis.html) text, nor does it provide access to the underlying [QMessageBox](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmessagebox.html).

However, if you're keen enough, you can roll your own. This code assumes Maya2020/PySide2:

```py
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtCore


box = QtWidgets.QMessageBox(
    QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Icon.Question,
    'Message title', 
    'Message body goes here.\n\nHere are some more words to make the size a bit more reasonable',
    QtWidgets.QMessageBox.StandardButton.Ok|QtWidgets.QMessageBox.StandardButton.Cancel,
    None,
    QtCore.Qt.Dialog|QtCore.Qt.MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint|QtCore.Qt.WindowContextHelpButtonHint
)
box.setWhatsThis('This is the WhatsThis text...')
box.button(QtWidgets.QMessageBox.StandardButton.Ok).setText('Import')
res = box.exec_()

if res == QtWidgets.QMessageBox.StandardButton.Ok:
    print('User wants import')
else:
    print('User wants to cancel')
```

It's worth pointing out that the question-mark-box/WhatsThis text probably isn't what you're hoping it will be. Run the above example and see if it fits your needs.

Cheers